# How can I turn an icon or image upside-down?

Tags: image, image-processing, photoshop

[This favicon.ico file](http://en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico) has "W" in it. I want to change the direction of the "W" so that it is upside down. It will look like "M" and the file format will be the same.

How is it done?

Comment: honestly why couldn't you have just googled this?

Comment: @Luke: I suspect I could find the answer to most of the questions you've asked using Google, too. That doesn't mean they're bad questions, or shouldn't be asked here. It's been discussed many times before over on the Meta site that we don't discourage people from asking before Googling. If our goal for SO to become the canonical resource for programming-related material, we have to actually create content here. (Of course, this question *is* still off-topic. Several people have already voted to migrate it to a more appropriate site; I suspect that'll happen in short order.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged the question "Photoshop", I'm going to assume that you have a copy of Photoshop.

1. Open the image you want to rotate in Photoshop.
2. From the "Image" menu, click "Rotate".
3. In the dialog box that appears, enter the number of degrees that you want to rotate the image.
4. Save the file.

If you *don't* have Photoshop, you will need to download and install an image manipulation program. Since this is an icon, I recommend [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/). It's a free download, and an incredibly powerful icon editor.